# circleCI - How to run job when has change in specific directory

Tags: github, workflow, pipeline, git-diff, circleci

I'm using circleCI version 2 and my `config.yml` like this:

```
version: 2
jobs:
   a:
     steps:...
   b:
     steps:...
workflows:
  version: 2
  main_pipeline:
    jobs:
       - a
       - b
```

I want only to build when a change happens in the directory.

`job a` for folder a
`job b` for folder b

when `folder a` changes, build only `job a`.

Comment: [It can also be checked by comparing revisions (HEAD and subdirectory last change)](https://gist.github.com/naesheim/18d0c0a58ee61f4674353a2f4cf71475)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function trigger_job() {
    job_name=$1
    curl --user ${CIRCLE_API_TOKEN}: \
        --data build_parameters[CIRCLE_JOB]=$job_name \
        --data revision=$CIRCLE_SHA1 \
https://circleci.com/api/v1.1/project/github/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_USERNAME/$CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME/tree/$CIRCLE_BRANCH
```

I use this function for trigger job and find different by git-diff like this `git diff-tree --name-only $(git log -n 2 --pretty=format:"%H") | grep project`

Answer (score 1):

CircleCI now has support for dynamic configs (instead of a single static config file), and with that a `path-filtering` orb is available that can detect changes under a folder and set pipeline parameters accordingly.

See https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/using-dynamic-configuration/#execute-specific-workflows-or-steps-based-on-which-files-are-modified

You can also check out [our config](https://github.com/ethereum/sourcify/blob/master/.circleci/config.yml)